# consolidate argparse if else calls to single statement

Tags: python-3.x

I have lot of if else calls to get user input from command line like:

```
if args.action == ‘a’:
    apiobj = func(name = args.name, age=args.age)
    apiobj.call_main()
elif args.action == ‘b’
    apiobj = func(name = args.name, age=args.age, dob=args.dob)
    apiobj.call_main()
elif args.action == ‘c’
    apiobj = func(name = args.name, age=args.age, school=args.school)
    apiobj.call_main()
… so on..
```

is there a better way to write this in a one consolidated statement?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, may be it will help someone in future:

```
if args.action == ‘a’ or ‘b’ or ‘c’:
    apiobj = func(name = args.name, age=args.age, nargs=2, dob=args.dob, school=args.school)
    apiobj.call_main()
```

Comment: you should fix your code :) `if` is lowercase. also, this doesn't work. but you can write: `if args.action in ("a", "b", "c")`

Comment: try setting "action" to "d", this line will still run. the problem is that it's actually (action==a) or (b) or (c)